# Model inheritance, translated to the database

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Ok, so I have the following code:

```
class Player < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :wanted_league
  belongs_to :league
end

class League < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :players
end

class WantedLeague < League
  belongs_to :player
end
```

I only made the inherited class: 'WantedLeague' because 'Player' both belongs_to a League and has_one League.

So my question is: How do I migrate this to the database? Since there is no 'WantedLeague' table in the database.

```
create_table :players do |t|
  t.League :actual_league
  t.WantedLeague :wanted_league
end
```

Is this right or do I use `t.League :wanted_league`?

Comment: Umm, Ruby on Rails uses STI, which mean a single table represents data from two different sub types. Now, there are way of achieving MTI, but creating a `WantedLeague` table will be useless if you've setup the model to inherit from League.

Comment: When you say "I only made the inherited class: 'WantedLeague' because 'Player' both belongs_to a League and has_one League" : Why dont you use a has_and_belongs_to_many relationship between Player and League ? You could identify wanted league in association table LeaguePlayer with an attribute as "wanted" ?